# Cloud Functions Firebase - create directory in default bucket - typescript

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a function that updates a node in database and then create a directory in the default storage bucket.

```
admin.database().ref('messages').push({ original: original })
    .then(() => {
       //looking for something like this
       //functions.storage.object().mkdir('myFolder');
    })
```

Function [samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/89c08865065b04090c0f6fbe8aedb9a86b4ab540/ffmpeg-convert-audio/functions/index.js) from firebase docs use `const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();` but i am having hard time importing this package using typescript.

importing it this way does not work. instead of having access to *gcs.bucket(...)* i have access to *gcs.Bucket*

```
  import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage';
```

I am looking for ways to get this import working or other ways i can use in typescript.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage does not have a concept of "folders" -- as a pure object store, you can store a file with any arbitrary key. Various UIs (including the Firebase console) look for slashes in the object names to provide a virtual structure, but no actual structure exists.

On the import issue -- as of version 5.2.0 of the Admin SDK, you can just do:

```
admin.storage().bucket()
```

to get a reference to the Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: The only thing usable for what i am trying to do is admin.storage().bucket().upload(...) function. To use this i have to create local temp file on the server using mkdirp before uploading it to the bucket by giving it the server file path...seems long way to just create a folder/file in a bucket. you would think admin.storage().bucket().ref(...) would work for the default bucket...

Comment: @michael-bleigh is this syntax still valid, or did it from the beginning require default bucket name specified in some way rather to be automatically inferred by the SDK? Using this out the box on Admin 8.12.1 produces: _Getting Unhandled error { Error: Bucket name not specified or invalid. Specify a valid bucket name via the storageBucket option when initializing the app, or specify the bucket name explicitly when calling the getBucket() method._

Comment: How did you initialize the app? There needs to either be a `storageBucket` option in the args to `initializeApp()` (or in the default discovered credentials) or you need to pass it explicitly.